# Getting no results from simple Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've tried the following and it returned me every Tutor

```
List<Tutor>tutorsList = tutors.ToList();
```

Furthermore, I tried to select only Tutors with a specific subject (Tutor-Subject is n:n)

```
Subject subjectEntity = subjects.Where(s => s.Name == input).FirstOrDefault();
List<Tutor>tutorsList = tutors.Where(t => t.Subjects.Contains(subjectEntity)) .ToList();
```

As a result, my `tutorsList` is empty, even `subjectEntity` is correct (I printed it to console).
But when I loop every Tutor and print the Subjects, there is a Tutor with Subject `input`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `tutors` in your code?

Comment: And `subjects`? I think they are in-memory collections, and the `Contains`  is doing a reference-comparison.

Comment: they were Code-First created using EF4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also have id's, you can do the following:

```
Subject subjectEntity = subjects
    .Where(s => s.Name == input)
    .FirstOrDefault();
List<Tutor> tutorsList = tutors
    .Where(t => t.Subjects
        .Select(x => x.SubjectId)
        .Contains(subjectEntity.SubjectId)
    )
    .ToList();
```

If not, you can try to do it in a single query

```
List<Tutor> tutorsList = tutors
    .Where(t => t.Subjects.Any(x => x.Name == input))
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Thank you, both worked fine. I was not aware, that Contains is doing a reference-comparison.

Answer (score 1):

simplify in one line, using `Any`, when working on an inner collection.

```
var tutorsList = tutors.Where(t => t.Subjects
                                    .Any(s => s.Name == input)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
Subject subjectEntity = subjects.Where(s => s.Name == input).FirstOrDefault();

List<Tutor>tutorsList = tutors.Where(t => t.Subjects.Any(x=>x.UniqueField==subjectEntity.UniqueField)).ToList();
```